# Get QGIS layer symbology as xml string using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, xml

Analogue to saving a layers symbology into a *.qml file I would like to have the xml content of a layers symbology in a python string (or `QDomDocument`). I think the method [`QgsVectorLayer().writeSymbology()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a0c6948e03b3f40a94271b9ae19bfa3a2) does what I'm after, but I'm unsure how to use its parameters properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works with `QgsMapLayer().exportNamedStyle()` the following way (here for the active layer):

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument
>>> d = QDomDocument()
>>> iface.activeLayer().exportNamedStyle(d, '')
>>> s = d.toString()
>>> s
u'<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC \'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd\' \'SYSTEM\'>\n<qgis version="2.18.21" simplifyAlgorithm="0" minimumScale="0" ...
```

(Works for QGIS 2.18 and 3.4)

Comment: For PyQGIS 3.18, the error message string isn't an Input parameter anymore, but a return from the `exportNamedStyle()` function (same for `importNamedStyle()`). Otherwise, this solution still works. See [QgsMapLayer API documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.exportNamedStyle).